# Get previous td from a input onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following tr:

```
<tr>
    <td>My Text</td>
    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" value=" Test " onclick="myFunc(this);" /></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to get the text "My Text" from previous td

```
function myFunc(obj){
    console.debug($(obj).closest('td').previous('td').text());
}
```

However, it is returning: `TypeError: $(...).closest(...).previous is not a function`

Isn't closest() a function?

Thanks

Comment: Use `.prev()` instead of `previous()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery it's `.prev('td')` not `.previous('td')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with **previous** function as mentioned in the **"error message"**.

As Eddie rightly mentioned.

```
function myFunc(obj){
    console.debug($(obj).closest('td').prev('td').text());
}
```

use this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have jQuery installed and the jquery library script is running before your javascript and also that the parameter of your function is actually a valid jQuery query.

Also `.prev()` would probably be what you want more than `.closest`

Comment: jquery isnt the issue . else error message would have been different